# Checking out a maven project from a git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, m2eclipse, egit

I have installed m2eclipse and EGit, I can checkout a project from a git repository and I can build a maven project, but I cannot checkout a maven project from the git repository.
The problem is, that the SCM URL field is empty (apart from EGit I have SVN team providers as well...) and when I paste the url I just get `SCM provider is not available` in the maven console.
I tried searching for this issue and I found I have to install m2eclipse SCM integration and SCM handler for git, however those aren't on the update sites.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven SCM integration in Eclipse used to be good.  It used to be that you could do Import > Check out Maven projects from SCM and put in a URL like scm:git:ssh://git@git:project.git but in Helios or the new version of m2eclipse + extras you can't do that anymore.  It always gives the error that the original post is talking about.  Disappointing that you have to check out in EGit and then add dependency management.  This isn't a great solution because it isn't smooth with parent / children POMs.

Comment: yeah, looking forward to support in Indigo

Comment: seems so for me(juno), had to install the m2e scm egit bridge however.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so now it works. First clone the repository with EGit, then create generic project, then add dependency management and everything installs just fine and works.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your saying, I can do what you need in this way. Just place this in the projects' pom.xml:

```
<scm>
        <connection>scm:git:https://gitUsername@github.com/gitRepo/projectname.git</connection>
        <url>scm:git:https://gitUsername@github.com/gitRepo/projectname.git.git</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://gitUsername@github.com/gitRepo/projectname.git.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>
```

A git project is not checked out, it's cloned.

To clone the project just type

```
git clone <project url>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution to my problem. I use Apache Ivy (IvyDE, plugin for Eclipse) instead and the thing I want to checkout is in the default dependency repository.